# tcolorbox: remove frame of single tcb item

Tags: tcolorbox

Using `tcbitemize` I created three columns of boxes. But for one of them I want to remove the frame and resize the inner boxes to the outer frame.

This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raster,most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,sharp corners,
        colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule=1.0pt,
        raster equal height,raster force size=false,
        raster equal skip=0.2pt,raster column skip=1mm,
        raster columns=3]
        \tcbitem[width=0.30\linewidth]
        \vspace{2cm}
        ABC
        \vspace{2cm}
        \tcbitem[width=0.40\linewidth]
        \vspace{2cm}
        DEF
        \vspace{2cm}
        \tcbitem[width=0.30\linewidth]
        \begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,sharp corners,
            colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule=1.0pt,
            raster equal height,raster force size=false,
            raster equal skip=1pt,raster column skip=-1mm,
            raster columns=2]
            \tcbitem[width=0.5\linewidth+0.5mm]
            \centering
            GHI
            \vspace{0.9cm}
            \tcbitem[width=0.5\linewidth+0.5mm]
            \centering
            JKL
            \vspace{.1cm}
            \tcbitem[width=1.0\linewidth]
            \centering
            \vspace{0.1cm}
            MNO
            \tcbitem[width=0.0\linewidth]
            \tcbitem[width=1.0\linewidth]
            \centering
            PQR
            \vspace{0.1cm}\\
        \end{tcbitemize}
    \end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

Figure underneath shows what I would like to have.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that?

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raster,most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\centering\mbox{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[size=fbox,sharp corners,
        colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule=1.0pt,
        raster equal height,raster force size=false,
        raster equal skip=0.2pt,raster column skip=1mm,
        raster columns=3]
            \tcbitem[width=0.30\linewidth]
                \vspace{2cm}
                ABC
                \vspace{2cm}
            \tcbitem[width=0.40\linewidth]
                \vspace{2cm}
                DEF
                \vspace{2cm}
            \tcbitem[width=0.30\linewidth,blanker,space to=\myspace]
                \begin{tcbitemize}[
                    raster height=\myspace,
                    size=fbox,sharp corners,
                    colframe=black,colback=white,boxrule=1.0pt,
                    raster force size=true,
                    raster equal skip=1pt,raster column skip=-1pt,
                    raster columns=2,raster rows=3]
                    \tcbitem
                      \centering
                      GHI
                      \vspace{0.9cm}
                    \tcbitem
                      \centering
                      JKL
                      \vspace{.1cm}
                    \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2]
                      \centering
                      \vspace{0.1cm}
                      MNO
                    \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2]
                      \centering
                      PQR
                      \vspace{0.1cm}
                \end{tcbitemize}
    \end{tcbitemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

I tried to keep the original code as unchanged as possible, but one would not need the enclosing `\mbox` and `minipage`.

Note that several compilations are needed for the final output.

Comment: `\myspace` is not recognized. Don't you need to define it first? Oh, and I removed the `\mbox` and `minipage`, thanks

Comment: @API `\myspace` is defined by `space to=\myspace`. This is a quite new option. Therefore, you should check, if you are using the current version `3.90 (2016/02/29)` of `tcolorbox` (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox).